# double that I converted into String adding int type

Tags: java, string

This is very weird. The following is the code:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
  double db = 56.00;
  String st = String.valueOf(db);
  System.out.print(st+3);
 }
```

The output that I get is

```
56.03
```

First, how come a String adding an int?Second, how is this possible that 56.00 + 3 is is 56.03?

Comment: The compiler changes `System.out.print(st+3);` to `System.out.print(new StringBuilder(st).append(3));` thus your output.

Comment: `56.00` is represented as `56.0`. There is no concept of meaningful numbers going on there -- only the notion that it is about a fraction (due to `double`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're performing string concatenation. The value of `st` is `"56.0"`, and then you're performing a concatenation of that and the `int` 3, giving a result of `"56.03"`.

The string concatenation `+` operator is described in [JLS 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1). It starts with:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

And [JLS 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) includes:

> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9):
>
> [...] If `T` is `byte`, `short`, or `int`, then use `new Integer(x)`.
>
> [...] Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"` is used instead.

In other words, your program in this case is basically:

```
double db = 56.00;
String st = String.valueOf(db); // "56.0"
System.out.print(st + new Integer(3).toString()); // "56.0" + "3" = "56.03"
```